# Why does Jekyll load navbar.less?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jekyll, github-pages

I am generating a site with Jekyll, locally and [on Github pages](http://advanceicare.github.io/). Both instances load up a navbar.less file (which is throwing off my navbar), but I cannot find in my code.

How is this navbar.less file getting loaded in?

Here is my head.html file:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <title>{% if page.title %}{{ page.title }}{% else %}{{ site.title }}{% endif %}</title>
  <meta name="description" content="{% if page.excerpt %}{{ page.excerpt | strip_html | strip_newlines | truncate: 160 }}{% else %}{{ site.description }}{% endif %}">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela+Round" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ "/css/style.css" | prepend: site.baseurl }}">
  <link rel="canonical" href="{{ page.url | replace:'index.html','' | prepend: site.baseurl | prepend: site.url }}">
  <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="{{ site.title }}" href="{{ "/feed.xml" | prepend: site.baseurl | prepend: site.url }}">
</head>
```

My [style.css file](https://github.com/advanceicare/advanceicare.github.io/blob/master/css/style.css) does not make reference to this. Could it be Bootstrap that's loading it in or Jekyll somehow?

Comment: Not reproduced both on gh-pages and after repository cloning. You're file is a ghost ! Did your cleaned browser cache ? Are you doing a `jekyll serve` in the right folder ?

Comment: It doesn't show in my sources but when I inspect the img tag of the logo in the navbar, one of the (essential) styles of it in Chrome inspector are from navbar.less. When I click that file to see what's in it, it opens a blank file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you see is a chrome/firefox interpretation of the [map file](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css.map) generated from less transformation. You can see a reference to it at the very end of you [bootstrap css file](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css). This file is here for [debugging preprocessor code like less or sass with chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/css-preprocessors).

In fact, your css rule is in bootstrap.min.css file.

You just have to overwrite it by replacing, in your `css/style.css` :

```
.navbar .navbar-header .navbar-brand img {
    max-height: 43px;
    margin-top: -14px;
}
```

by :

```
.navbar .navbar-header .navbar-brand img {
    max-height: 43px;
    margin-top: -14px;
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: That did it. I'm going to have to read over this again later to better understand exactly how Chrome/Firefox make this happen but thank you for this.