# Why does Bootstrap show a LESS file that is nonexistent when inspecting?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm working on a project and I was trying out how responsive my CSS was, and then my page suddenly changed its style for a bit, mainly my navbar (which is made with the help of bootsrap) just changed completely, when I inspect it I find it's getting properties from a less/navbar.less file that's supposedly in my css folder (that's what it says when I hover on it), but when I look into my css folder I find no such file, I'm quite sure I made no modifications to make this happen since I went back to the original state everything was in but the navbar still didn't change back, help please as this project is due soon.

Update : upon further inspection, it seems the bootstrap.min.css file is the one making this change, but it still confuses me how the same code appeared totally normal before but now without changing the code the navbar changed greatly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does Jekyll load navbar.less?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34713816/why-does-jekyll-load-navbar-less)

Comment: Unfortunately no

Comment: File maps show the _original_ location of the code, not the current location. Please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As weird as it sounds, redownloading bootstrap and replacing its old files fixed it, dunno how the old files got edited or corrupted, but they were the problem.